# Can I connect SATA harddrive to my laptop through USB port

Tags: hard-drive, usb-storage, usb-to-sata

I have 160 GB SATA harddrive in my PC, but my PC is **not** working. I want to copy my SATA hard drive data to my laptop. Is it possible to connect my pc hard drive to a laptop via USB?

Answer (score 3):

You need to a USB to SATA/IDE adapter.

You can find them cheaper than $20. Like this one on [Amazon for $15](http://smile.amazon.com/Sabrent-Converter-Activity-Support-EC-AHDD/dp/B00CPGYNV4/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1411767844&sr=8-1). Here another [USB to SATA/IDE](http://smile.amazon.com/Drive-Adapter-Converter-Optical-External/dp/B002OV1VJW/ref=sr_1_10?ie=UTF8&qid=1411767844&sr=8-10) one for $10.

I found a great video that explains the entire processing from [connecting your hard drive to your laptop USB](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZS-xTR7Puu8).

Comment: So no enclosure is needed?  The drive can lie bare on the surface?

Comment: For short term no. Long term its good to make it an external drive with enclosure

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do it! And I advise to have such a connector at home for emergency situations. Try something like this [SATA TO USB ADAPTER](http://www.hitmeister.de/usb-sticks/sata-to-usb-adapter-154266121/?utm_source=googlebase_direct&utm_medium=organic&id_unit=873830100242&ts=20121215_140329)

Answer (score 0):

You can connect it but with usb adapters see below links

http://www.cooldrives.com/usb2to4hddex.html
http://www.awd-it.co.uk/icy-box-ib-290stusd-b-aluminium-enclosure-2.5-sata-hard-drive-usb-and-esata-3.5-frame.html

2nd way is to buy a crossover lan cable, share the data and copy all of it. It is cheapest

Answer (score 0):

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812119152

I got one of these almost two years ago and it's been perfect for connecting arbitrary hard drives via USB. Supports both SATA and older IDE drives.

Answer (score -1):

Try Terabyte 2 in 1 External Hard Drive Casing .

Just check this unboxing video, you can find similer unboxing videos in your own language also.

https://youtu.be/TYtrX2x2nCQ

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.